# Class IDSSMS.ManagementObject cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, sms

This code receives text messages and it is tested and perfectly working on the other computer that i have.  I then recreated the system i have. coded it to the other computer manually. "not copy paste". As i manually code it, displays the error "Class "IDSMS.ManagementObject" cannot be indexed because it has no default property"

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Receiving_SMS
Public WithEvents NewSMS As New mCore.SMS

Public Function connectmodem() As String
    Dim modem As String
    Try
        Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "Select * from win32_POSTModem")
        For Each queryobj As ManagementObject In search.Get()
            If queryobj("Status") = "OK" Then
                modem = modem & (queryobj("attached") & "- " & queryobj("Description") & "***")
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As ManagementException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return ""
    End Try
    Return modem
End Function
```

[image: code]
[image]

Comment: `ManagementObject` is `System.Management.ManagementObject`. `IDSSMS.ManagementObject` is your own class.

Comment: any suggestions how to fix this one?

Comment: Try: `For Each queryobj As System.Management.ManagementObject In search.Get()`

Comment: @Loathing i tried what you suggested and i got an error which display "System.Management.ManagementObject is not defined".. hoping for your response

Comment: `Solution Explorer -> References -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> System.Management`

Comment: im using Visual Studio 2010 and ive already added the reference System.Management

Comment: Double check. `Imports System.Management` is available without explicitly adding the reference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Still cant find your answer as a solution

Comment: Well, the error message is a compile error that the indexer property `Default Public Property Item(ByVal name As String) As String` does not exist. Seems like a fairly straight problem to solve. Either you implement that property in your `IDSSMS.ManagementObject` class, or you are using the wrong class and need to fix your references.

Comment: thanks a lot now i saw where i was wrong. any way how can i thank you if you didn't even answer the question. i would have accepted your answer as a solution

Comment: Thank you is enough. Glad you figured it out.